# JQPL Custom Query

Tags: spring, jpa, jpql

I have this Spring JPA application I am working on in class and I'm trying to figure out how to get a custom query to work.  I have 3 tables setup with relationships( UserAccess -> Profiles -> Projects ).  I have this code that does work, BUT it gives me all of the projects in the table.  Not a specific users which I am trying to do by their userId.  I know normal SQL works in this matter but JPQL does not apparently.  Any help appreciated!

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Project,Integer>{

/*

select * from Projects where profID = 
(select profID from Profiles where userAccessID = 1);    

*/
@Query("SELECT p FROM Project AS p WHERE p.profID = (SELECT p.profID FROM Profile AS f WHERE f.userAccessId = (SELECT u.userAccessId FROM UserAccess AS u WHERE u.userAccessId = :userID))")
public abstract List<Project> find(@Param("userID") int userID);
```

}

Comment: JPQL simply GENERATES SQL. And have you looked at the SQL generated by this JPQL? in the log of whichever JPA implementation you use.

Comment: No I didn't realize it was doing that. I will check next time I have an issue! Thanks Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should the last bit of the query be `SELECT u.userAccessId FROM UserAccess AS u WHERE u.userId = :userID`?

Comment: I thought that the syntax is supposed to be in that format.  To pass in the parameter required. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Ahhh thx whistling!  I see the problem now! You directed my attention to the u.userid = :userid. It should be my attribute in my class called u.useracessid = :userid. Otherwise it is true =true which is all items :)